# Simple MVC RoutePrefix - HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, routes, prefix, asp.net-apicontroller

I have coded an `API controller`, and I wish to add a `RoutePrefix` to this controller.

My controller name is `MapCompanyController` and this controller has one method called `GetMapCompany`.

Currently, I can access this method by calling the following webaddress: `/api/MapCompany/GetMapCompany`

I wish to add a `RoutePrefix` so that the path to this method is: `/api/1_0/MapCompany/GetMapCompany`

This is what I have done:

1. I have added `[RoutePrefix("1_0")]` to the `MapCompanyController`
2. I have added `routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();` to the
   `RegisterRoutes` `RouteConfig`

After doing this, I can still access the method with the `/api/MapCompany/GetMapCompany` address, and the `/api/1_0/MapCompany/GetMapCompany` performs the following error:

```
HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found
```

Can I please have some help with this code?

Thanks in advance

**EDIT**

I have created a simple controller as follows:

```
public class TestRouteController : ApiController
{
    // GET: api/TestRoute/5
    public string Get(int id)
    {
        return "value";
    }
}
```

To get to the `Get` function, the following url is correct:

> api/TestRoute/5

If I change the code to be as follows:

```
public class TestRouteController : ApiController
{
    // GET: api/TestRoute/5
    [Route("routetest")]
    public string Get(int id)
    {
        return "value";
    }
}
```

What is the path to the `Get` function?

I have tried the following:

1. /api/TestRoute/5
2. /api/routetest/5
3. /routetest/api/TestRoute/5
4. /api/TestRoute/routetest/5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if this is trully a ApiController this should be registered with WebApiConfig not RouteConfig :

```
{
    public static class WebApiConfig
    {
        public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
            config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
        }
    }
}
```

and then in your global.asax :

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
```

routing in MVC and WebApi is different

**EDIT** :
defining route for your controllers and method is simple in webapi you just need to add a RoutePrefix attribute to your controller class and then you can add or not a Route attribute to your methods :

```
[RoutePrefix("api/TestRoute")]
public class TestRouteController : ApiController
{
    [Route("testroute")]
    [HttpGet()]
    public string Get(int id)
    {
        return "value";
    }
}
```

this way the route should be api/TestRoute/testroute?id=whatever

RouteConfig is for mvc "Controller", for webApi "ApiController" just register the routes like above and define them with attributes, no need of obscur RouteConfig :)

Comment: I have done as you have suggested, yet the route to the controller  is still the same with no change in the web address needed to get to the API controller.

Comment: Can you please have a look at my simple example? I am not sure of the path to get to a function when using a prefix for the route.